# getString() causes app to crash. The bundle.getArgument() is not null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

`bundle.getArgumentes()` is not null as i tested using `Toast.makeText`. Tested condition for `(bundle != null)` and `(bundle == null)`, it tells me it is not null

Main Activity - This function is inside `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener`. I want to pass the selected information to another fragment

```
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String dateName = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("mymonth", dateName);
            HomeFragment homefrag = new HomeFragment();
            homefrag.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,homefrag).commit();

        }
```

**HomeFragment - OnCreateView function**

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View ListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle == null){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "lolol",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    //String myMonth = bundle.getString("mymonth"); //if i uncomment this, it will cause app crash
    return ListView;
}
```

Comment: please add your error logcat to your question

Comment: show the exception and stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Here You Need to check getArguments() is null or not. refer below code,

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 

ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View ListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
            if(this.getArguments()!=null){
             bundle = this.getArguments()
                if(bundle == null){
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "lolol",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                 }else{
                     String myMonth = bundle.getString("mymonth");
                 }
           }else{
            // else part Here
           }

            return ListView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your `onCreateView` method for target fragment like below.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, 
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container, 
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    if(getArguments()!= null){
        bundle = getArguments()
        String myMonth = bundle.getString("mymonth");
     } else {  
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "lolol",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
     }
    return listView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking wrong, don't match with spinner view and get the selected item. It's the wrong way of doing.

Get from the callback onItemSelected() function.
You will get the adapter and position.

```
 ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(//Set the values);     
 spinner.adapter = adapter

 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){
        String dateName = adapter.getItem(i) ;
        **(OR String dateName = adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString())** 
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        if(dateName != null)
            bundle.putString("myMonth", dateName);
        HomeFragment homefrag = new HomeFragment();
        homefrag.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,homefrag).commit();
}
```

onCreateView of HomeFragment

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View ListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if(bundle !=null && bundle.containsKey("myMonth"))
       String myMonth = bundle.getString("myMonth"); 
    return ListView;
}
```

Use the KEY as Global it might be different declared and fetch. Better use the KEY in global declaration

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code in your HomeFragment**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        String myMonth = bundle.getString("mymonth");
    }
}
```